# Построение динамического графика

Tags: delphi

На форме два компонента `Tedit` и `Tchart`, нужно чтобы при изменении значений в `edit` менялся график `series1`, а меняются только значение в `Tchart` по оси Y

1. Как определить неизменные значение по оси Y в `Tchart`?
2. Как сделать что бы изменялся сам график `series1`?

   ```
   procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
   var a,b:integer;
   begin
       b:=strtoint(edit1.Text);
       series1.Clear;
       series1.AddY(b,'',clgreen);
   end;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно Вас понял:
Clear - команда, уничтожающая ВСЕ точки на данной кривой. AddY() - вставляет точку с указанной ординатой в данную кривую, вычисляя при этом абсциссу новой точки по своему алгоритму. Если Вы предварительно кривую стерли (Clear), то и для вычисления абсциссы у алгоритма нет никакой базы.

Comment: если убрать series1.Clear; там вообще будет каша которая будет накладыватся сама на себя после каждого изменения в edit